# Is there any meaningful use where the Paragraph.Parent property is not a FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

In a FlowDocument / WPF RichtTextBox the `Parent` property is of type `DependencyObject`. But I haven't found any meaningful case where Parent isn't a `FlowDocument` (or `null`).

Is there any?

**Edit:**

Why I need to know that?

My method gets a `Paragraph` as parameter and I don't know when it is called.

When Parent is `null` I know that the Paragraph is not integrated in any structure.

When parent is `FlowDocument`, I have to take that in account for my operations.

Do I have also take in account that it may be different from `null` or `FlowDocument`?

Comment: Please leave me a hint what's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for [Paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.paragraph?view=netframework-4.8) clearly says:

> Parent - Gets the parent in the logical tree for this element. (**Inherited from FrameworkContentElement**)

So it is inherited property, which is bound to have common base type and for Paragraph in reasonable cases will contain `FlowDocument` object.

---

Paragraph.Parent is not necessary FlowDocument. In the example from [FlowDocument Table official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-build-a-table-programmatically), the Parent of `new Paragraph(new Run("2004 Sales Project"))` paragraph is a `TableCell`:

```
// Create and add an empty TableRowGroup to hold the table's Rows.
table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());

// Add the first (title) row.
table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());

// Alias the current working row for easy reference.
TableRow currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];

// Global formatting for the title row.
currentRow.Background = Brushes.Silver;
currentRow.FontSize = 40;
currentRow.FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold;

// Add the header row with content, 
currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("2004 Sales Project"))));
// and set the row to span all 6 columns.
currentRow.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 6;
```